# Problems with the sessions and HAProxy in OpenShift

Tags: haproxy, node.js, redis, openshift-online-2

I have written an application using Kraken and deploy in OpenShift with the option of auto-scaling (use HAProxy) but this has led me two problems:

1) HAProxy constantly sends requests to the application, this resulted in a week has ~485k sessions stored in my redis.
2) Because of the constant requests HAProxy every time I try to see my log (using: RHC taill myapp) my logger shows a lot of these requests are useless to me.

Is there any way to fix this

Comment: I'm guessing these are the health checks, not legitimate requests?  You can check the health of the application via other methods (separate port, run a script, etc) instead of connecting to the regular application.  Please post a santized config if you need more assistance.

Comment: see Simon's answer here. http://serverfault.com/a/792154/366174
http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/snapshot/configuration.html#inter

Answer (score 0):

Session files may be created by the `haproxy's http health checks`. Check your access logs and `haproxy.cfg`'s `option httpchk GET /`.

though I've experienced this on `php`, same "solution" might be applied.

**Answer:**

set `httpchk` target path the a dedicated path for checking and use a non persistent session driver.